# Is there an OpenVMS EDT keypad plugin for geany?

Tags: editor, geany, openvms

Is there [a](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=openvms+%22the+open+is+silent%22) [OpenVMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS) [EDT](http://www.openvms.compaq.com/doc/73final/6489/6489pro_contents_003.html#toc_chapter_9) [keypad](http://www.openvms.compaq.com/doc/73final/6021/6021pro_019.html#eve_edtequivs_ax) ([layout](http://openbookproject.net/tutorials/kjcole/kbd-edt.html)) plugin for [geany](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geany)?

Comment: Do you have an [LK201](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LK201) keyboard, or do you have some other mapping in mind? (And thanks for the _a_ link.)